# How I get Input text string value to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

**I'm still learning Javascript and I need to get input type text value to javascript code and convert it to integer. but everytime it display "Your fail" even i input higher mark. I need help to find my error.**

```js
function mark() {
    var sMark = document.form.mark.value;
    var myMark = parseInt(sMark);
    if (myMark > 75) {
        document.write("You  pass exam with Higher mark");

    } else if (myMark > 50) {
        document.write("You pass exam");

    } else {
        document.write("You Fail");
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="form">
        Enter Your Mark: <input type="text" name="mark" id="mark1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="mark()"><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: You may also want to read this related question: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

1. Use the `<label>` element to display text that is related to an input element.
2. Don't use `document.write()`, just don't.
3. Use `type="number"` for an `<input>` element if you'd like to just receive numbers.
4. Using `onclick` is bad practice. Register event listeners using `addEventListener()` instead.

```js
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const form = document.forms['mark-form'];

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { mark } = e.currentTarget.elements;
    const value = mark.valueAsNumber;

    switch (true) {
        case value > 75:
            result.textContent = 'You pass with a higher mark.';
            break;
        case value > 50:
            result.textContent = 'You pass the exam.';
            break;
        default:
            result.textContent = 'You fail.';
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>
<form name="mark-form">
    <label for="mark-input">Enter your mark:</label>
    <input type="number" name="mark" id="mark-input" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: For `<input type="number">`, just use `mark.valueAsNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

The input with the name `"mark"` is shadowing the global `mark` function in the inline `onclick` handler. Either rename those or directly call `window.mark()`.

```js
function mark() {
  var sMark = document.form.mark.value;
  var myMark = parseInt(sMark);
  if (myMark > 75) {
    document.write("You  pass exam with Higher mark");

  } else if (myMark > 50) {
    document.write("You pass exam");

  } else {
    document.write("You Fail");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="form">
  Enter Your Mark: <input type="text" name="mark" id="mark1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="window.mark()"><br>
</form>
```